# Is there a way to load another website login page, wait for it to be submitted, then read the location querystring?

Tags: php

I need to load the login page of another website (different domain), wait for the user to fill it in and submit it, then read the `URL/Location/Querystring` for a token parameter to my site and close the login page.

Don't want the **username or password**, only interested in the returned token (`http://www.othersite.com/?token=blahblahblah`), which will then be passed as a `querystring` to a page on my domain (`http://www.mydomani.com/loadtoken.php?token=blahblahblah`).

Currently, a user has to do this in a separate page, copy and paste the token into my page, since these tokens only have a short life, it's somewhat irritating practice, and if it can be done behind the scenes by the site instead it would make it simpler for everyone.

Reading around on `iframes`, `div`s and `ajax` suggest this is not possible due to security policies, cross site scripting, etc.

Is it possible? What should I be looking for or concentrating on, or can you give some examples.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Should have said, I understand that it's possible to take the username and password and do a POST behind the scenes, but I really want to avoid making the users give my site their login details to another site, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible due to cross-browser scripting concerns.

Comment: Depending in your reasons for needing the token, the other site may have a system in place (like openid for example) where it will allow you to call it with a url to return the token to.

Comment: Would be nice, but unfortunately not. Reason for the token is being able to prove ownership of that account on the othersite without supplying the sensitive login information. Also, permits them to use one set of credentials to login for both sites without exposing the credentials to my site. A mini openid I guess. Since my site is an extention/related to the other site, makes sense to reuse the credentials if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to present the login form on your own site. The form posts to your server, and the handling script then does a CURL request to do its own request to the other server. This sends the login response (which presumably contains that token) to your server.

However, if this token takes the form of a cookie, and the cookie's required for the user to do further operations on their own on this other site, then this won't work. There is absolutely no way for your server to accept the cookie on the user's behalf, then send the cookie to the user in such a way that it appears to have been set by the other server.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid, not having to accept the user's login credentials, for the simple fact they won't be willing to enter them, and why I use the token generated from it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for you to post that form's information to the remote host and have that site send the token to a callback script on your own host.

Comment: I have no control over the site to direct it back to my site unfortunately, so I need a way to allow the user to login, then read the final url and get the token from it. They can do this manually in the web browser, two tabs and copy and paste, but it's annoying of course.

Comment: Use OAuth or something similar then, I suppose.. if the other site supports it at least.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to load the login page of another website (different domain), wait for the user to fill it in and submit it, then read the URL/Location/Querystring for a token parameter to my site and close the login page.

[You can't do that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

> What should I be looking for

[OAuth / XAuth](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/04/xauth_oauth_and_yahoo_openid/) (which will require the co-operation of the site you are trying to log in to)

Comment: Yeah, what all my research tells me so far, darn. OAuth / XAuth, hmm.. not likely